# '${}' this syntax is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

Title='${}' this syntax is not working in javascript

'${ variablename}' when this syntax used in string, this have to give variable value, but it prints as it is.
console.log( '${ variablename}' ) this must have to give variable, value but it prints as it is.

what should i do to solve this issue?

Comment: you need backticks `\`` for wrapping.

Comment: it also not support

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks (`) instead of apostrophes (') like this:

```js
const x = "Hello World";
console.log( `${x}` );
```